# www.softwarecollections.org is down - is there an alternative

Tags: centos, yum

I've a centos based installation with php-56 installed from this repository. 
It looks like this site is down.

Any idea where can I find a mirror or replacement ?

it looks like instead of looking for another mirrors yum just keep hitting the same site again and again:

> https://www.softwarecollections.org/repos/remi/php56more/epel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://www.softwarecollections.org/repos/remi/php56more/epel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30000 milliseconds')
>   Trying other mirror.
>   https://www.softwarecollections.org/repos/remi/php56more/epel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 12] Timeout on https://www.softwarecollections.org/repos/remi/php56more/epel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: (28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds')
>   Trying other mirror.

Comment: looks like you using the remi reository http://rpms.remirepo.net/

Comment: yes but softwarecollection site is down. I see I got remi installed as well, but it doesn't find the file I need there (gmp)

Comment: actually I see now that  remi-php56more-epel-7-x86_64.repo also points to : https://www.softwarecollections.org/repos/remi/php56more/epel-7-x86_64

Comment: Notice: php56more is now deprecated and will not receive any updates, you should use centos-sclo-sclo instead, see https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2017/02/23/Additional-PHP-packages-for-RHSCL

Comment: Thanks, my goal is to run away from php5.6 anyway. the code base is too big to do it right now :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to install Software Collections directly from an official CentOS repo. To enable that repo, run:

```
yum install centos-release-scl
```

See the [CentOS SCL wiki page](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/SCL#head-9c6aea9c13b921d5258446c4c5e5886571bdb741) for details. The repo itself is at http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/.

Comment: It might had worked, but the site returned... so all is good now.